# How to create distance matrix with known distance?

Tags: python, distance-matrix

I have a csv. file that looks like:

```
| Start| End | Distance|
|------|-----|---------|
| A    | B   |        1|
| A    | C   |        2|
| B    | C   |        3|
```

The desired output is a list of number like:

```
[[0,1,2],
 [1,0,3],
 [2,3,0]]
```

Does anyone know how to code it in Python?

Thank You!

Comment: does the csv actually have | (pipes) as separators?

Comment: oh no, it's only for illustration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a simple answer for the problem using squareform:

```
import pandas as pd
from scipy.spatial.distance import squareform

df = pd.read_csv('File Name.csv')
distance_matrix = squareform(df['Distance']).tolist()
print(distance_matrix)
```

Output:

```
[[0,1,2],[1,0,3],[2,3,0]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You mention that you have a `csv` file, so assuming you also have a `DataFrame`:

```
def construct_dist_matrix(df):
    alphabet = np.unique(df[["Start", "End"]].values.ravel("K"))
    lut = {x: i for i, x in enumerate(alphabet)}
    n = len(lut)
    mat = np.zeros((n, n))

    for _, row in df.iterrows():
        s, e, d = row
        s = lut[s]
        e = lut[e]
        mat[s, e] = d
        mat[e, s] = d

    return mat, lut
```

Test run:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({
...     "Start": ["A", "A", "B"],
...     "End": ["B", "C", "C"],
...     "Distance": [1, 2, 3],
... })

>>> mat, lut = construct_dist_matrix(df)

>>> mat
array([[0., 1., 2.],
       [1., 0., 3.],
       [2., 3., 0.]])

>>> lut
{'A': 0, 'B': 1, 'C': 2}
```